# Using SQL Server Designers from .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, com

This is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853162/how-to-call-sql-server-management-studios-query-designer-from-c-application), but the other one didn't get any answers, so I'll have another go.

I have SQL Server 2008 Client Tools installed, and would like to use SQL Server's query designer(s) in my application, for working with queries, views, SPs and functions. I'm pretty sure Access ADP does this, can I?

I guess what I am hoping for is that these designers are COM objects which I can use via p/invoke.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you would have to implement the functionality yourself, but, it really shouldn't be that hard to do, technically, but will be a time-consuming project.